# can't upload using fupload in php+wamp

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, phpmyadmin

i dont know why this error, please help, i have been looking everywhere, but no relevant.

```
$lokasi_file = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']; 
$nama_file = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
```

it say Undefined index: fupload in c

and

Undefined index: kategori in C

```
if (!empty($lokasi_file)){ 
  move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file,"images/$nama_file"); 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_berita(judul, 
    id_kategori, 
    isi_berita, 
    id_user, 
    jam, 
    tanggal, 
    hari, 
    gambar)VALUES('$_POST[judul]',
    '$_POST[kategori]',
    '$_POST[isi_berita]',
    '$jam_skrg',
    '$tgl_skrg',
    '$hari_ini',
    '$_SESSION[namauser]'
    '$nama_file')",$connection);
```

Comment: You should maybe post your html formular source code.

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?? sry im new

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include "../config/SkripKoneksi.php"; 
// Apabila variabel session masih kosong (user belum login) 
if (empty($_SESSION['namauser']) AND  
empty($_SESSION['passuser'])){ 
echo "<center>Untuk mengisikan berita, Anda harus login <br>"; 
echo "<a href=form_login.php><b>LOGIN</b></a></center>"; 
} 
// Apabila user sudah login dengan benar terbentuklah session 
else{ 
echo "<h2>Tambah Berita</h2> 
<form method=POST action=input_berita.php 
 enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
<table> 
<tr><td>Judul</td>      
<td> : <input type=text name=judul size=60></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Kategori</td>  <td> :  
<select name=kategori> 
<option value=0 selected>- Pilih Kategori -</option>"; 
$tampil=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_kategori  
      ORDER BY nama_kategori"); 
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($tampil)){ 
echo "<option value=$r[id_kategori]> 
$r[nama_kategori]</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Isi Berita</td> 
<td> : <textarea name=isi_berita cols=80 rows=18></textarea> 
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>Gambar</td>     
<td> : <input type=file name=fupload size=40></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan=2><input type=submit value=Simpan> 
<input type=button value=Batal onclick=self.history.back()> 
</td></tr> 
</table> 
</form>"; 
} 
?>
```